# How to deal with two identical forms in a page?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html, forms

I'm developing a Landing Page in WordPress that outputs the same CF7 form twice, once at the top, and once at the bottom of the page. I'm having a few issues, mainly because of duplicated IDs, as for example I can't set an input mask selecting by ID, and as this same form is used in other pages, I wish it could be the same form especially to have a single place in case of changes.

Comment: umm..use class instead of ID? That is the most common approach for handling duplicate ID

Comment: Probably better to fix the problem that causes the same form to be duplicated on your page with identical ids

Comment: Can you wrap the embedded CF7 form in a class? .form-1 #someID is different than .form-2 #someID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your issues are exactly, but if you want to distinguish between two CF7 forms on the same page and select inputs you can do the following:

- Embed the form twice an either wrap them both in a div with a unique id
- Select the form inputs using the parent, for example: `var select=document.querySelector("#form1 > #input");` (or alternatively `querySelectorAll`).

Example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="form1"><p id="test">Content1</p>
    <div id="form2"><p id="test">Conten2t</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then the JS `document.querySelector("#form1 > #input");` will select the first nested child.

(Arguably the nicest solution would be if ids would be unique, but I don't know if CF7 supports embedding a form multiple times while keeping unique ids. Or select the inputs based on other (custom) properties and the parent.)

Comment: Solves the issue in a rather simple way I didn't think of, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use class instead of id,
then add event listeners to both

let $forms = $('.form-class')

$forms.on('submit', function() {...})

Comment: I used jQuery here because it is automatically loaded with WordPress. It's easy to implement it in pure js as well

Answer (score -1):

if you are using jquery give the forms a class instead and you can do jQuery('.form_id').first().whatever_function_you_want_to_call() and to get the last form replace first() with last()

Comment: `$(idSelector)` will always point to the first and only the first since ID's must be unique